# How to programmatically add WPF binding between DependencyProperty objects on 2 separate windows

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

The problem I am having is probably very simple to solve, yet it seems tricky from beginner's perspective.

I created 2 windows visible simultaneously, one with ListBox on it, another with TextBox. I would like to bind window1.ListBox.SelectedValue to window2.TextBox.Text property programmatically. I am not using value converters.

The code is straightforward:

```
      var binding = new Binding("SelectedValue");
      binding.Source = window1.ListBox;
//      binding.Path = new PropertyPath(ListBox.SelectedValueProperty);
      var bound = window2.TextBox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

I would like to bind using DependencyProperty instance instead of property name for performance reasons, but I also tried binding by name. Binding just does not work.

You can download dummy VS2010 project [here](https://turecki.net/download/so/dummy.7z).

This leads to another question - how to debug binding, which event (if any) to subscribe to detect Binding changes ?

Comment: Are your two windows seperately created in your App.xaml.cs? or does one window open the other window (i.e. is one window the parent window of another)?

Comment: window1 is created as main window, window2 is created on first AppActivate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved - I mistakenly called SetBinding with a TextBlock.TextProperty, when it should be TextBox.TextProperty.